# Android - Only getting notification sound, no actual notification with text

Tags: android, notifications

This is the code that I'm using. I can hear that the notification is working, but no text.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    showNotification(context);
}

private void showNotification(Context context) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MyActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: if there is no sound then how can you hear?

Comment: there is sound, no text, sorry,

Comment: let try this by implementing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an icon  `new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Answer (score 3):

if you are using support-v4 library the use this code

```
private void showNotification(Context context) {
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, DashBoard.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.getNotification());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
```

Comment: I am getting sound, no visual notification, sorry